# iframe video loads twice (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a page with modal that contains a mix of iframe youtube videos and regular videos.
Regular videos work fine. But when I click on the modal with iframe, iframe video loads twice. After debubugging, I realized that this code causes it to load twice. But I need this code or else the video doesn't pause when I close the modal or click outside the modal.

```
element.src = elementSrc;
```

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function pauseVideo(element) {
        if (element.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
            element.pause();
        } else if (element.tagName === 'IFRAME') {
            var elementSrc = element.src;
            element.src = elementSrc;
        }
    }

    var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.test--img-gallery');

    modals.forEach(function(modal) {
        var closeButton = modal.querySelector('[data-close-modal]');
        var video = modal.querySelector('video');
        var iframe = modal.querySelector('iframe');

        closeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            pauseVideo(video || iframe);
        });

        modal.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (event.target === modal) {
                pauseVideo(video || iframe);
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (!modal.contains(event.target)) {
                pauseVideo(video || iframe);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

HTML code -

```
<div class="usa-modal usa-modal--lg test-modal--img-gallery" id="modal--exhibit-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal--exhibit-1-heading" aria-describedby="modal--exhibit-1-description">
<div class="usa-modal__content">
<div class="usa-modal__main">
<h2 class="usa-modal__heading" id="modal--exhibit-2-heading">dfdf</h2>

<iframe width="860" height="415" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/dfdfdff" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>

<button type="button" class="usa-button usa-modal__close" aria-label="Close this window" data-close-modal><svg class="usa-icon" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img"><use xlink:href="/images/c-clamp-images/sprite.svg#close"></use></svg></button></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code forces iframe to reload. don't do that, tell the page in the iframe to stop the video:

Example if youtube embed

> Note: please add `?enablejsapi=1` after url youtube embed iframe

```js
  function pauseVideo(element) {
        if (element.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
            element.pause();
        } else if (element.tagName === 'IFRAME') {
           element.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*')
        }
    }
```